# develop such winform using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, image

Figure 1，i have one or a few pictures，and some mp3 files. i want to develop a winform and load picture into winform，then, when mouse over certain areas of the picture，the area change，and play mp3 file when the mouse click.

question：How do I know the mouse over the designated area？and then change the color of the area？ how to know which areas of mouse clicks？ and play mp3 files

These areas may be round, oval, rectangular...
perhaps this is hotspot image question.

anyone help me？ thanks！

[image: Figure]

Comment: I would recommend using WPF instead of WinForms. In Winforms we have Mouse Events like OnMouseDown/OnMouseUp/OnMouseMove which you can use and accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OvalShape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.ovalshape.aspx) and the [MouseHover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shape.mousehover.aspx) event. Then simply call code to modify the opacity/color/whatever of the oval, and play an mp3 which is a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to create a hidden bitmap of the same size with a white or black background, and shade each bubble with a different color.

Then you can just do something like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int foundColor = _Mask.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToArgb();

  if (foundColor == Color.Red.ToArgb())
    // do something with this bubble
  else if (foundColor == Color.Blue.ToArgb())
    // do something with this bubble
  else
    // do nothing
}
```